# Ajax отправляет данные даже если форма не прошла валидацию

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function ValidPhone() {
  var re = /^(\s*)?(\+)?([- _():=+]?\d[- _():=+]?){12,12}(\s*)?$/;
  var myPhone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  var valid = re.test(myPhone);
  if (valid) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#form").submit(function () {
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "send.php",
          data: form_data,
          success: function () {
          },
          error: function () {
          }
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
  } else {
    document.getElementById('message-err').style.display = "block";
  }
  return valid;
}
```

Здравствуйте. Ajax отправляет данные даже если форма не прошла валидацию. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: обычно к форме привязывают обработчик отправки, в котором проверяют валидность, и если не проходит, то возврат. А не единожды проверив валидность приделывают обработчик который далее всегда выполняется.

Comment: Я думаю, что условие всегда возвращает `true`. Консольните.